# Firebase + Swift: Grab only the latest change for a child node

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `locations-orders` table that looks like this:

[image]

I want to only grab the latest order that is added to the record (not all the other orders that are already inside it). This is what I have, which doesn't work (fyi I hardcoded the location-orders key):

```
  static func observeOrders(lId: String, f: @escaping (AppState.Order) -> () ) {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "locations-orders/5P9TF215PZ3ZV")
      .child("orders")
      .queryEnding(atValue: nil)
      .queryLimited(toLast: 1)
      .observe(.childAdded, with: { firebaseSnapshot in

      let orderObject = firebaseSnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

      print("orderObject")
      print(orderObject) // <-------------------- only prints once, never prints again


      let order = AppState.Order(
        title: orderObject["name"] as! String,
        subtitle: orderObject["item_variation_name"] as! String,
        createdAt: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(orderObject["created_at"] as! Int / 1000)),
        name: "name",
        status: AppState.Order.Status.Pending
      )

      f(order)
    })
  }
```

What's wrong with my query??

Answer (score 3):

Let's simplify. If you want to get the last item added and then any new items added, how about this:

```
let ref = "your orders path"
ref.queryLimited(toLast: 1)
   .observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
     print(snapshot?.value) 
})
```